# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Maven shaded jar for salesforce API jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, salesforce

I have an Apache Maven Java project that imports the class:

com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection

When running the project from IntelliJ, I have no problems executing the code. However, I want to be able to run the project from the command line as a shaded jar. I have been shading the jar using 'mvn package'. When I run the jar from the command line I am getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sforce/soap/enterprise/EnterpriseConnection

My pom includes dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>qa-integration.sfdc</groupId>
  <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/enterprise-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>qa-integration.sfdc</groupId>
  <artifactId>metadata</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/metadata-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

My shade execution looks like the following:

```
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.sunrun.integration.sfdc.metadata.Main</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

When I list the contents of the jar, I see no salesforce files at all.

Comment: Check If your shaded jar contains this class.

Comment: That error says that dependency is not on your classpath. How are you building your jar?

Comment: @SilverShroud No the jar does not contain the class.

Comment: @SamOrozco I am building using 'mvn package'

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and my solution was to add the following snippet to my pom.xml:

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>corrigo.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>2.4</version>-->
                    <!--<configuration>-->
                        <!--<archive>-->
                            <!--<manifest>-->
                                <!--<mainClass>corrigo.Main</mainClass>-->
                            <!--</manifest>-->
                        <!--</archive>-->
                    <!--</configuration>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Then you just run `mvn package`. 
Here is a reliable resource: 
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/